# CYOA book, Tre-something, dragon, "half a hundred years"?

Tags: story-identification, choose-your-own-adventure

Can anyone put a name to a choose-your-own-adventure style gamebook?  The title was *Tre*-something, you know, a [Cornish name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tre,_Pol_and_Pen#:%7E:text=Tre%20in%20the%20Cornish%20language,emphasis%20on%20the%20second%20syllable.).

There was a prologue story about a dragon in a cave, and some knights came into the cave, I think they were after her eggs.  The knights were not likeable characters if I remember rightly.  There was something about stagnant water, and something about "half a hundred years".

The 'choose your own adventure' part probably started when the half a hundred years after that were up.

Comment: Do you mean a literal CYOA-branded book? Because there's a complete list of them available here and none of them match your description of the title; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Choose_Your_Own_Adventure_books

Comment: I don't think it was one of them, no, or at least I have no reason to think so, or I would have looked it up.  I was referring to the genre, not the series.  That's how I usually see the genre referred to.

Comment: Fair enough. The genre generally are 'gamebooks' rather than CYOA which is a specific brand (think biro versus ballpoint)

Comment: Ah, I see. If I saw "gamebook" I'd think you meant a book that was part of a game, like a D&D sourcebook - so... yeah, the jargon gets complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be [Dragon's Lair](https://gamebooks.org/kngtmare.htm), the 6th in a series of story/gamebook publications based on the Knightmare TV show.

The game master in the series also features in the books, and was called Treguard - if you conflated the character with the book title, that would fit.

It includes a dragons cave, and there is mention of making a stagnant pool into clean water. 'Half a hundred' is a line - but refers to pinches of the dust of dragon eggs, not years.

Comment: That's the one!  I recognise the cover now I see it, apart from anything else.  Don't know how I jumbled those up.  Funny to see it again after all these years.